# How to prevent the console window from closing after running a program in Sublimetext3 on Windows?

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3, build-system

New to Sublime,here's my current build system:

```
{
"windows":
    {
    "cmd": ["g++", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall","&","start", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
    },
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

It would be nice to edit the build system so that the cmd window would not close after finishing the program.(Idealy same as **system ("pause")** at the end of the program or **pause** in .bat files)

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html -> using "cmd /k g++" should do the trick

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `cmd /?` and read the output help. There is the parameter `/K` which means *keep open/running* in comparison to parameter `/C` meaning *close/exit*.

Comment: @stijn Thanks,its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following setting:

`Menu > Preferences > Settings`

```
// Shows the Build Results panel when building. If set to false, the Build
// Results can be shown via the Tools/Build Results menu.
"show_panel_on_build": true,
```